# Subtract value from given criteria in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to subtract a specific value from a certain column if both columns match a criteria. As well as creating a new column that would contain what is being subtracted.

**Data**

```
start   id  q1_avail    q1_used 
50      aa  10          40  
20      bb  5           15
```

**Desired**

```
start   id  q1_avail    q1_used    delta
50      aa  8           40         2
20      bb  4           15         1
```

Logic

we are looking for the 'q1_avail' column as well  as the id 'aa'.
we are then subtracting the value 2 from 10 under the q1_avail column
the value 2  is what is being subtracted from 10 .
10-8 = 2

**Doing**

```
mask = df['q1_avail'] 

df.loc[mask, 'q1_avail] -= out['id'].map({'aa':2,
                                          'bb':1,})
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `aa` is always subtract 2 and `bb` is always subtract `1`?

Comment: `delta = start - (q1_avail + q1_used)`

Comment: @fam-woodpecker it can change but it is whatever I input

Comment: why not `df.apply(function)` to run function on every row and do what you need - you could use `if/else` and check values in `id` and substract `2` or `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use normal `.apply(function, axis=1)` to run `function` on every row separatelly and this `function` could use `if/else` to check value in `id` and change `q1_avail` and create `delta`

---

Minimal working example

```
text = '''start   id  q1_avail    q1_used 
50      aa  10          40  
20      bb  5           15'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep="\s+")

def function(row):
    if row['id'] == 'aa':
        row['q1_avail'] -=2
        row['delta'] = 2
    if row['id'] == 'bb':
        row['q1_avail'] -=1
        row['delta'] = 1
    return row

df = df.apply(function, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   start  id  q1_avail  q1_used  delta
0     50  aa         8       40      2
1     20  bb         4       15      1
```

---

You may also create more complex `function` and even get parameters but then you need to use `lambda`

```
def function(row, maps):
    
    row['delta'] = maps[row['id']]
    row['q1_avail'] -= row['delta']

    return row

df = df.apply(lambda row:function(row, {'aa':2, 'bb':1}), axis=1)
```

---

**EDIT:**

With your last code it could be

```
df['delta'] = df['id'].map({'aa': 2, 'bb':1})

df['q1_avail'] = df['q1_avail'] - df['delta']
#df['q1_avail'] -= df['delta']
```

Comment: Thank you @furas I am getting: TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame

For this line: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep="\s+") , is the 'text' string the actual dataframe?
I am doing:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(out), sep="\s+") :  'out' is the name of my dataframe file. ex like pd.read_csv("out.csv")

Comment: I used `io.StringIO` only to simulate file in memory. For normal file you should use `pd.read_csv("out.csv")`